# How do I associate an NVME drive name with a PCIe address?

Tags: ssd, pci

NVME uses the PCIe bus. How do I find the PCIe address (for example, 00:00.0) associated with the drive's name (such as /dev/nvme0n1)?

Comment: Try `ls -l /sys/block/nvme0n1` and look where the symlink points to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ls -l /sys/block/blockdevice
```

should tell you the complete path to the device, including the PCI bus. For example:

```
martin@martin ~ % ll /sys/block/sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 20 21:36 /sys/block/sda -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/
```

Comment: I don't fully understand why the simulink gives this information, but further down the hierarchy, I have to hunt for the same information, but this solution is absolutely perfect. Thank you!

Comment: `/sys` is a special filesystem that is populated by the kernel with a lot of useful information that comes directly from the kernel. `/sys/block` just contains a list of all available block devices, and the kernel developers intentionally used symlinks there so that you can not only determine information about the block device itself, but also figure out how exactly this block device is connected to your computer.